# How to use arguments specified in a user-created R function?

Tags: r, function

this seems like a basic question; however, I am not sure if I am unable to word my question to search for the answer that I need.
This is the sample:

```
id2  sbp1 dbp1 age1 sbp2 dbp2 sex     bmi1     bmi2 smoke drink exercise
1   1 134.5 89.5   40  146   84   2 21.74685 22.19658     1     0        1
2   4 128.5 89.5   48  125   70   1 24.61942 22.29476     1     0        0
3   5 105.5 64.5   42  121   80   2 22.15103 26.90204     1     0        0
4   8 116.5 79.5   39  107   72   2 21.08032 27.64403     0     0        1
5   9 106.5 73.5   26  132   81   2 21.26762 29.16131     0     0        0
6  10 120.5 81.5   34  130   85   1 24.91663 26.89427     1     1        0
```

I have this code here for a function I am making:

```
linreg.ols<- function(indat, dv, p1, p2, p3){
    data<- read.csv(file= indat, header=T)
    data[1:5,]
    y<- data$dv
    x <- as.matrix(data.frame(x0=rep(1,nrow(data)), x1=data$p1, x2=data$p2, 
         x3=data$p3))
    inv<- solve(t(x)%*%x)
    xy<- t(x)%*%y
    betah<- inv%*%xy
    print("Value of beta hat")
    betah
}
```

And when I run my code with this line:

```
linreg.ols("bp.csv",sbp1,smoke,drink,exercise)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(x0 = rep(1, nrow(data)), x1 = data$p1, x2 = data$p2,  :
```

arguments imply differing number of rows: 75, 0

I have a feeling that it's because of how I am extracting the p1, p2, and p3 columns on the line where I create the x variable.

EDIT: changed to y<-data$dv
EDIT: added on part of the sample. Also, I tried:

```
x <- as.matrix(data.frame(1,data[,c("p1","p2","p3")]))
```

But that returned the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c("p1", "p2", "p3")) : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: `indat` is a character string, but `$` operators are meant for a `list` or a `data.frame`. You might mean to use `y <- data$dv`?

Comment: Hello! I have fixed that error but now, it gives me this error once it runs in to that x<- line:
Error in data.frame(x0 = rep(1, nrow(data)), x1 = data$p1, x2 = data$p2,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 75, 0

However, I know that this line should work since I've tested the chunk outside of a function and it runs smoothly

Comment: Your more recent error suggests that you have at least one column name incorrect. For instance, `data$quux` will return `NULL`. Now try `data.frame(x=1, y=NULL)` and see what happens. (It might be helpful if you include sample data, perhaps as `dput(head(data))` ... both for us and for yourself to realize what is actually in the data.)

Comment: maybe try `cbind(1,data[,c("p1","p2","p3")])` or use `data.frame(1,data[,c("p1","p2","p3")])`

Comment: Hello! I added a sample of the data @r2evans
I know that the column name isn't incorrect since when I try the same line of code outside of the function, it works fine. However, I need to specifically put it in a function

Comment: Also @Onyambu I tried your suggestion but no luck. Thank you though! Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You cannot use `$` when `p1` is a variable holding a character string representing the column you want. Try `data[[p1]]` (and repeat for all others).

Comment: @r2evans This worked! Thank you so much. And I think I understand the error. I ran the function and called it and it gave me the output. Thank you all!